# How to pass a value from JQuery to servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

Here is my Script:

```
<script>
 $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

var metrics_key = $('.createAlarm').val();
var metrics_label = $(".createAlarm option:selected").text();

// Now you have the key and label in variables.

// Write the key into the textfield.
$('#myModal input[name="name"]').val(metrics_key);
// Change the HTML of an element to the label.
$('#myModal label[for="priority"]').html(metrics_label);
});

   var val = $('#priority').text();

   $.post("/<pjtname>/createAlarm", { val : "val"});
</script>
```

I have a createAlarm class in a JSP page and clicking on a button from that page, pops up the following modal:

```
 <!-- Modal- Create Alarm -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
       <h4 class="modal-title">Create Alarm</h4>
     </div>
    <form action="/CMPE283_Project2/createAlarm" method="post" id="addcard" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
   <div class="modal-body" style="height: 170px;">
       <div class="form-group" style="height: 30px;">
            <label for="title" class="col-md-3 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="alarmName">
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="form-group" style="height: 30px; margin-bottom:30px;">
            <label for="title" class="col-md-3 control-label">Description</label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
               <textarea class="form-control" name="desc"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

           <div class="form-group">
            <label for="priority" id="priority" name="priority" class="col-md-3 control-label"> </label>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                <select name="metric" class="form-control">
                <option value="lessthan"><</option>
                <option value="greaterthan">></option>
                <option value="lessthanequalto"><=</option>
                <option value="greaterthanequalto">>=</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="metricnum">
                </div>
               </div>
            </div>
           </div>
```

I want to pass the value of the label for priority to a servlet page. I tried:

```
String val = request.getParameter("val");
```

But, I am getting null value. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: do you have multiple fields with the id=priority ?

Comment: try to do `alert($('#priority').text())` before submiting. What value do you get?

Comment: alert is displaying the correct value I want to pass to servlet.

Comment: try this then, it should work `$.post("/<pjtname>/createAlarm", { val : $("#priority").text()});`

Comment: This this didn't work, still passing null value to the servlet. :(

Comment: do you have multiple fields with the id=priority ?

Answer (score 0):

$('#priority').text() to get value from html content .First Use post or get method inside Jquery to submit value to servlet. below link help to use get / post method.
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp